# How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{\cos(a) - \cos(x)}\mathrm{d} x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How do I integrate
$$\int \frac{1}{\cos(a) - \cos(x)} \mathrm{d} x?$$

Is there a a substitution or any other method?

Please help

Comment: I have edited your post, please make sure the edits are correct. By the way, welcome to Math.se! :D

Comment: Try the half angle tangent substitution.

Comment: @jeel thnx for the edit. I'm on my mobile :D

Comment: @user170231 thank-you! Will try that

Comment: Nope its not the correct substitution

Comment: Is $a$ a constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{\cos a-\cos x}dx\;,$$ Put $\displaystyle \cos x = \frac{1-\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}.$

So $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}{\cos a+\cos a\cdot \tan^2 \frac{x}{2}-1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}dx = \int\frac{\sec^2 \frac{x}{2}}{[\cos a-1]+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}\cdot [1+\cos a]}dx$$

Now Using $$\displaystyle 1+\cos a = 2\cos^2 \frac{a}{2}$$ and $$\displaystyle 1-\cos a = 2\sin^2\frac{a}{2}.$$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{2\cos^2 \frac{a}{2}}\int\frac{\sec^2 \frac{x}{2}}{\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}-\tan^2\frac{a}{2}}dx$$

Now Let $\displaystyle \tan\frac{x}{2}=t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \sec^2\frac{x}{2}dx = 2dt$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{\cos^2 \frac{a}{2}}\int\frac{1}{t^2-\tan^2\frac{a}{2}}dt = \frac{1}{\cos^2\frac{a}{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{2\tan \frac{a}{2}}\cdot \ln \left|\frac{t-\tan \frac{a}{2}}{t+\tan \frac{a}{2}}\right|+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{\cos a-\cos x}dx = \frac{1}{\sin a}\cdot \ln \left|\frac{\tan \frac{x}{2}-\tan \frac{a}{2}}{\tan \frac{x}{2}+\tan \frac{a}{2}}\right|+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: Thank you. It works.. I approved your answer!