# Center of mass of the semi cylindrical shell.

Tags: calculus

I have to find the x and z co-ordinates of the centre of mass.

Here is finding the x;

$$V \bar{x} = \int_{-l}^0x dV$$

$$\implies \pi r \delta r l \bar{x} = \int_{-l}^0x\pi r \delta r \delta x$$
$$\implies \pi r \delta r l \bar{x} = -( \frac{l^2}{2} \pi r \delta r) $$
$$ \bar{x} = - \frac{l}{2} $$

and if I substitute the values in, I get the correct answer.

I am having trouble with the z-coordinate. Could someone give me a hand please.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an circular arc.

r - z = 2r/pi

z = [r (pi-2)]/ pi

Where r is the radius

Comment: I'm really sorry, could you explain this a little more please.

Comment: The curved surface can be considered as an arc when u take an alement piece fron it.

Comment: And cntr of grvty of a circular arc is sin(a)/ a which u can prove by integration

Comment: The above is when u measure from center of the arc

Comment: So when considering ur reference origin (shown in the figure) r - x = rsin(pi/2) / (pi/2)

Comment: x =  [r (pi - 2)/ pi]

Comment: Im really sorry my previous answer is WRONG

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: You're welcome! :) if you're nt busy can u help me with this integration ==> http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259523/how-to-integrate-int-frac1-cosa-cosx-mathrmd-x

Comment: For a prismatic object we need consider only a line cross-section.

Comment: @Narasimham could you elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The Z center of mass is always half of max Zvalue for extruded/parallely displaced prismatic geometrical objects due to symmetry.Also Y center of mass is 0 for same reason. Z of center of mass as per what others have given by integration. Hand sketch you marked radius $r$ is better chosen from shell center rather than on the shell itself to exploit symmetry and so simplicity.